# I'm trying to parse a string to a date field in an android application

Tags: android

I'm using multiple DatePickers and I want to parse a string to a date. I want to check if these two dates are in right order and then insert them into datebase. I want to use flags so if dates are in right order flag would be true, but it doesn't work.

Please help!

Here is code:

```
 public class Newreservation extends Activity {

        public TextView startDateDisplay;
        public TextView endDateDisplay;
        public ImageButton startPickDate;
        public ImageButton endPickDate;
        public Calendar startDate;
        public Calendar endDate;
        public EditText email2, something;
        public EditText mess;
        public ImageButton send;
        public static String flag = " ";
        public static Date date11 = null;
        public static Date date21 = null;
        public static String ff, zz;
        public static SimpleDateFormat form = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy ");


        static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;

        public TextView activeDateDisplay;
        public Calendar activeDate;

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.reservation);

            email2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.email2);
            mess=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.mess);
            something=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.something);
            send = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.send);
            Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
            String email = bundle.getString("email");
            String id_ad = bundle.getString("ad");
            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), " " + email + " " + id_ad, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            /*  capture our View elements for the start date function   */
            startDateDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.begin);
            startPickDate = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.beg);

            /* get the current date */
            startDate = Calendar.getInstance();

            /* add a click listener to the button   */
            startPickDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    showDateDialog(startDateDisplay, startDate);
                }
            });

            /* capture our View elements for the end date function */
            endDateDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.end2);
            endPickDate = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.end);

            /* get the current date */
            endDate = Calendar.getInstance();

            /* add a click listener to the button   */
            endPickDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    showDateDialog(endDateDisplay, endDate);
                }
            });

            /* display the current date (this method is below)  */
            updateDisplay(startDateDisplay, startDate);
            updateDisplay(endDateDisplay, endDate);



             ff = startDateDisplay.getText().toString();
             zz = endDateDisplay.getText().toString();

            send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                //HERE STARTS MY PROBLEM
                try 
                {
                    date11 = (Date) form.parse(ff);
                    date21 = (Date) form.parse(ss);

                    if(date11.after(date21)){
                        //flag = "true";
                     Log.d("Nesto", "Date1 is after Date2");

                    }
                    else if(date11.before(date21)){
                        //flag = " ";
                        Log.d("WWWWW", "Date1 is before Date2");


                    }else if(date11.equals(date21)){
                        //flag = " ";
                        Log.d("WWWWW", "Date1 is equal to Date2");

                    }else{
                        //flag = "true";
                        Log.d("WWWWW", "How to get here?");

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                //HERE ENDS MY PROBLEM


                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if(something.getText().toString().matches("") || email2.getText().toString().matches("") ||
 mess.getText().toString().matches("") || 
startDateDisplay.getText().toString().equals(endDateDisplay.getText().toString() ||)
                        flag.matches(" "))
                {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
Newreservation.this);
alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Info");
alertDialogBuilder
                    .setMessage("You have not selected something or dates are wrong")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setNegativeButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

                    // create alert dialog
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                    // show it
                    alertDialog.show();

                }
                else
                {

                    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            Newreservation.this);
alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Info");
alertDialogBuilder
                    .setMessage("You have clicked: \n" + something.getText().toString() + "\n" + email2.getText().toString() + "\n" 
                    + mess.getText().toString() + "\n" + startDateDisplay.getText().toString() + "\n" + endDateDisplay.getText().toString() + "\n" )
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setNegativeButton("Next",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

                                    //HERE GOES CODE FOR INSERTING INTO DATABASE
                                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Inserted",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                }
                            })
                            .setPositiveButton("Back",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });

                    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();


                    alertDialog.show();
                }
            }

        });

        }
        public void updateDisplay(TextView dateDisplay, Calendar date) {
            dateDisplay.setText(
                    new StringBuilder()
                    // Month is 0 based so add 1
                    .append(date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).append("-")
                    .append(date.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1).append("-")
                    .append(date.get(Calendar.YEAR)).append(" "));}

        public void showDateDialog(TextView dateDisplay, Calendar date) {
            activeDateDisplay = dateDisplay;
            activeDate = date;
            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
        }

        public OnDateSetListener dateSetListener = new OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                activeDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                activeDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                activeDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                updateDisplay(activeDateDisplay, activeDate);
                unregisterDateDisplay();
            }
        };

        public void unregisterDateDisplay() {
            activeDateDisplay = null;
            activeDate = null;
        }

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
            switch (id) {
            case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
                return new DatePickerDialog(this, dateSetListener, activeDate.get(Calendar.YEAR), activeDate.get(Calendar.MONTH), activeDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
            super.onPrepareDialog(id, dialog);
            switch (id) {
            case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
                ((DatePickerDialog) dialog).updateDate(activeDate.get(Calendar.YEAR), activeDate.get(Calendar.MONTH), activeDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is the problem here?

Comment: In your catch `(Exception e)` add a `Log.d(HERE_YOUR_TAG, "Exception!", e);` and post the stacktrace here. (i think it's a `ParseException`) after you fixed the crash, try to avoid `catch (Exception ex)` every where in your code.

Comment: You mena something like this:

Comment: catch (Exception e) 
      {
          e.printStackTrace();
          Log.d("Something", "Exception!", e);
      }

Comment: This part of code doesn work: try 
 { date11 = (Date) form.parse(ff);
date21 = (Date) form.parse(zz);
if(date11.after(date21)){
//flag = "true";
Log.d("Nesto", "Date1 is after Date2");
 }
else if(date11.before(date21)){
//flag = " ";
Log.d("WWWWW", "Date1 is before Date2");
}else if(date11.equals(date21)){
//flag = " ";
Log.d("WWWWW", "Date1 is equal to Date2");
}else{
//flag = "true";
Log.d("WWWWW", "How to get here?");
}}
catch (Exception e) 
{ e.printStackTrace(); }